# How to determine a website is using CA cert or SSL cert?

Tags: ssl, https, certificate, x509certificate, ca

Good day,

First of all, I am new to this, and I am not sure whether my question will being down vote or not. (As myself also not sure my question is valid question or not.)

Is it certificate is categorized into 2 types? 1 is CA, and another 1 is SSL?

If yes, how to check a website is using a CA cert or SSL cert?

Kindly advise.

Comment: Check `Basic Constraints` certificate extension. If it is presented and `CA=True`, then it is CA certificate, otherwise it is end entity certificate.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it certificate is categorized into 2 types? 1 is CA, and another 1 is SSL?

No. There are CA-signed certificates and self-signed certificates.

> If yes, how to check a website is using a CA cert or SSL cert?

No. You can check for a self-signed certificate by checking the length of the peer certificate chain. If 1, it is self-signed.